# I can't install the first version of any Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

When I try to install the 1.8.7 version of Ruby:

```
rvm install 1.8.7
```

He actually install Ruby 1.8.7-head (1.8.7 patchlevel 376).

How can I install the real first version (http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.7.tar.gz)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rvm install 1.8.7 -l 0
```

or

```
rvm install 1.8.7-p0
```

RVM is installing the latest patchlevel by default, so you need to specify the patchlevel that you want.